# OpenXML document with repeating row won't open (in OpenOffice)

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm creating a new open xml document. When I write unique data/rows to the document I can open it a variety of programs. When I write a non-unique row and attempt to open the document in Apache OpenOffice I get an error `General Error. General input/output error.` Obviously this isn't very descriptive so I'm assuming I'm creating my document wrong but I'm not sure what is missing/wrong

Things I've tried:

- The solution listed in the [OpenOffice Documentation](https://www.openoffice.org/documentation/HOW_TO/misc/Troubleshooting_guide.html#7.General%20error%20or%20General%20input/output%20error%20|outline)
- Using the OpenXmlValidator

  - This doesn't return any errors
- Opening in different software: Microsoft Office Excel Viewer and LibreOffice Calc.

  - The file opens in these but the machines running this code don't have this software installed
- The weird fix

  - Rename the a.xlsx => a.zip
  - Extract the contents from the zip file
  - Zip up all the contents (using winrar and windows compressed zipped folder) named b.zip
  - Rename the b.zip to b.xlsx
  - The file now opens in OpenOffice without any error.
  - Doing a diff on the unzipped files shows no differences, doing a diff on a.xlsx and b.xlsx there are differences but nothing that makes sense to me

The Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var thing = new MyClass();
        thing.GenerateDoc();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class MyClass {

        public MyClass() { }

        public void GenerateDoc() {
            var xmlFileString = "Temp.xlsx";
            var sheetName = "sheetName";
            var OpenXMLAlwaysPrintHeader = true;
            try {
                bool fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(xmlFileString);
                if (!fileExists) {
                    // check for a blank file template and copy that if it exists
                    CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(xmlFileString, sheetName);
                }
                fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(xmlFileString);
                if (fileExists) {
                    UInt32 RowIndex;

                    using (var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xmlFileString, true)) {
                        // Check to see if the sheet we are adding data to exists
                        var workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
                        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
                        try {
                            worksheetPart = GetWorksheetPart(workbookPart, sheetName);
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }


                        var sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet ?? new Worksheet();
                        var sheetData = sheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                        var t = sheetData.Elements<Row>();
                        Row eHeader = null;
                        if (t.Count() > 0) {
                            eHeader = t?.First(); // This should be the first row ( the header or key of each item in the dict)
                        }
                        RowIndex = (uint)t.Count() + 1;

                        // Create the table of all strings if it doesnt exist
                        SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart;
                        if (doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().Count() > 0)
                            shareStringPart = doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
                        else
                            shareStringPart = doc.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();

                        // Create a row for the header and the values (referring to the keys and the values in the dict)
                        Row header = new Row() { RowIndex = RowIndex++ };
                        Row data = new Row() { RowIndex = RowIndex };
                        // If we are not re-printing the header than the data row needs to shift up by 1
                        if (!OpenXMLAlwaysPrintHeader && t.Count() > 0)
                            data.RowIndex = --data.RowIndex;
                        var ColIndex = 1;

                        // Create the DefinedNames part which is a dictonary of "string" to a range of cells
                        // todo fix the next line
                        // This deletes all other pre-defined names since I can't figure out how to update a defined name yet
                        var dfns = new DefinedNames();
                        workbookPart.Workbook.DefinedNames = dfns;

                        /*
                        data.RowIndex = data.RowIndex - 1;
                        // Row 1
                        InsertObjectAt("Test1", data.RowIndex, ColIndex++, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                        InsertObjectAt("TestB", data.RowIndex++, ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                        // Row 2
                        InsertObjectAt("Test2", data.RowIndex, --ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                        InsertObjectAt("TestB", data.RowIndex++, ++ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                        // Row 3
                        InsertObjectAt("Test1", data.RowIndex, --ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                        InsertObjectAt("TestB1", data.RowIndex++, ++ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                        // Row 4
                        InsertObjectAt("Test2", data.RowIndex, --ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                        InsertObjectAt("TestB1", data.RowIndex++, ++ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);

                        // */
                        sheet.SheetDimension = new SheetDimension() { Reference = "A1:B4" };

                        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                            if (!OpenXMLAlwaysPrintHeader && t.Count() > 0) // Look up which column we want to insert our value into
                                {
                                var indexOfItem = InsertSharedStringItem("Key", shareStringPart);
                                var cells = eHeader.Elements<Cell>().Where(x => x.CellValue.InnerText == indexOfItem.ToString());
                                if (cells.Count() < 1) continue;
                                var cell = cells.First();
                                ColIndex = GetColumnIndex(cell?.CellReference).Value;
                            } // Otherwise we are always inserting a header so don't bother looking up where things should go
                            else {
                                //Insert for the header
                                InsertObjectAt(ColIndex%2 == 0 ? "TestB" : "Test1", header.RowIndex, ColIndex, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                            }

                            // Insert for the data
                            if (RowIndex == 2) {
                                InsertObjectAt((i % 2 == 0 ? "Test2" : "TestC"), data.RowIndex, ColIndex++, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                            }else {
                                InsertObjectAt((i % 2 == 0 ? "Test2" : "TestD"), data.RowIndex, ColIndex++, worksheetPart, shareStringPart);
                            }
                            /*
                            if (!OpenXMLAlwaysPrintHeader) // If we are not always printing a header we can create a named range for the column 
                                CreateRange(workbookPart, "key", sheetName, data.RowIndex, ColIndex - 1);
                        // */

                        }
                    }
                }
                var validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
                int count = 0;
                var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (ValidationErrorInfo error in validator.Validate(SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xmlFileString, true))) {
                    stringbuilder.Append("\r\n");
                    count++;
                    stringbuilder.Append(("Error Count : " + count) + "\r\n");
                    stringbuilder.Append(("Description : " + error.Description) + "\r\n");
                    stringbuilder.Append(("Path: " + error.Path.XPath) + "\r\n");
                    stringbuilder.Append(("Part: " + error.Part.Uri) + "\r\n");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e = e;
            }
        }
        private string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber) {
            int dividend = columnNumber;
            string columnName = String.Empty;
            int modulo;

            while (dividend > 0) {
                modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
                columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
                dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
            }

            return columnName;
        }

        public void CreateRange(WorkbookPart wbPart, string Name, string SheetName, uint RowIndex, int ColIndex) {
            var definedNames = wbPart.Workbook.DefinedNames;
            var myLocation = GetExcelColumnName(ColIndex) + RowIndex.ToString();
            var Col = GetExcelColumnName(ColIndex);
            var Text = string.Format("{0}!${1}${2}:${3}${4}", SheetName, Col, 2, Col, RowIndex);
            var colRange = new DefinedName { Name = Name, Text = Text };
            wbPart.Workbook.DefinedNames?.Append(colRange);
        }

        private static int? GetColumnIndex(string cellReference) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellReference)) {
                return null;
            }

            //remove digits
            string columnReference = Regex.Replace(cellReference.ToUpper(), @"[\d]", string.Empty);

            int columnNumber = -1;
            int mulitplier = 1;

            //working from the end of the letters take the ASCII code less 64 (so A = 1, B =2...etc)
            //then multiply that number by our multiplier (which starts at 1)
            //multiply our multiplier by 26 as there are 26 letters
            foreach (char c in columnReference.ToCharArray().Reverse()) {
                columnNumber += mulitplier * ((int)c - 64);

                mulitplier = mulitplier * 26;
            }

            //the result is zero based so return columnnumber + 1 for a 1 based answer
            //this will match Excel's COLUMN function
            return columnNumber + 1;
        }

        private void InsertObjectAt(object item, uint RowIndex, int ColIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart, SharedStringTablePart sharedStringTablePart) {
            if (item == null) return;
            if (item is ICollection)
                item = ICollectionToString(item as ICollection);
            // Create the header cell
            int index = InsertSharedStringItem(item.ToString(), sharedStringTablePart);
            Cell c = InsertCellInWorksheet(GetExcelColumnName(ColIndex), RowIndex, worksheetPart);
            c.CellValue = new CellValue(index.ToString());
            c.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);

        }

        private static int InsertSharedStringItem(string text, SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart) {
            // If the part does not contain a SharedStringTable, create one.
            if (shareStringPart.SharedStringTable == null) {
                shareStringPart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
            }

            int i = 0;
            // Iterate through all the items in the SharedStringTable. If the text already exists, return its index.
            foreach (SharedStringItem item in shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>()) {
                if (item.InnerText == text) {
                    return i;
                }

                i++;
            }

            // The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem and return its index.
            shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(text)));
            shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Save();

            return i;
        }

    public static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName) {
        Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
        if (sheet == default(Sheet)) {
            CreateSheet(workbookPart, sheetName);
        }
        return workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;
    }

        public static void CreateSheet(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName) {
            var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheets>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (sheets == default(Sheets))
                sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

            var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetdata = new SheetData();
            var worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetdata);

            worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;

            var id = (UInt32)workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Count() + 1;

            var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = id, Name = sheetName };
            sheets.AppendChild(sheet);
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        }

        public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath, string sheetName) {
            // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
            // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
            SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
                Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
            WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
            Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
                AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            var id = (UInt32)workbookpart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Count() + 1;
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() {
                Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                SheetId = id,
                Name = sheetName
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

            // Close the document.
            spreadsheetDocument.Close();
        }

        private string ICollectionToString(ICollection item) {
            try {
                var result = string.Empty;
                if (item is IDictionary) {
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in item as IDictionary) {
                        if (kvp.Value is ICollection)
                            result += kvp.Key + " { " + ICollectionToString(kvp.Value as ICollection) + " } ";
                        else
                            result += kvp.Key + " => " + kvp.Value + " |";
                    }
                }
                else if (item is IList) {
                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string thing = serializer.Serialize(item);
                    result += thing;
                }
                else {
                    // todo 
                }

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

    }



    // Given a column name, a row index, and a WorksheetPart, inserts a cell into the worksheet. 
    // If the cell already exists, returns it. 
    private static Cell InsertCellInWorksheet(string columnName, uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart) {
        Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        string cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;

        // If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
        Row row;
        if (sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).Count() != 0) {
            row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
        }
        else {
            row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex, Spans = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "1:2" } };
            sheetData.Append(row);
        }

        // If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.  
        if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == columnName + rowIndex).Count() > 0) {
            return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).First();
        }
        else {
            // Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
            Cell refCell = null;
            foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>()) {
                if (cell.CellReference.Value.Length == cellReference.Length) {
                    if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, true) > 0) {
                        refCell = cell;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
            row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

            worksheet.Save();
            return newCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Running the program once will create what I believe is a valid openxml document which will open in Apache OpenOffice. Running the program twice will add two lines of which 1 is not unique to the document. This will cause the error to show up in OpenOffice, but not in the other programs (Excel Viewer/Libreoffice Calc).

Unfortunately I need to use OpenOffice as its whats installed on the computers, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong when creating the document. Do I need to add something to the rows to indicate that it is a duplicate?

Edit: To run the code you need the DocumentFormat.OpenXML nuget package

Edit1: This only occurs when running the program twice. If I were to just append a 4 rows two of which were identical and attempt to open the file I have no issue. Note that the InsertObjectAt method also opens the document everytime (once for each cell so 4 rows by 2 cols = 8 times).